# toEqualData matcher breaks tests in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, gulp-karma

I have the following very simple test written for an AngularJS application's services:

```
describe('Services', function () { 

    beforeEach(function(){
        this.addMatchers({
            toEqualData: function(expected) { 
                return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
            }
        });
    });

    beforeEach(module('myapp.services'));

    describe('Album service', function(){
        var Album;

        beforeEach(inject(function (_Album_) { 
            Album = _Album_;
        }));

        it('can get an instance of the Album factory', inject(function (Album) { 
            expect(Album).toBeDefined();
        }));
    });
});
```

I've just added the custom toEqualData matcher [as advised in the AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11). However, this breaks the test. I'm using Gulp to run the test with `gulp-karma` (although the same issue occurs if I use Karma directly), and I see the following error message:

```
$ gulp test
[10:00:04] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/myapp/gulpfile.js
[10:00:04] Starting 'jshint'...
[10:00:04] Starting 'karma'...
WARN `start` method is deprecated since 0.13. It will be removed in 0.14. Please use
  server = new Server(config, [done])
  server.start()
instead.
31 07 2015 10:00:04.362:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
31 07 2015 10:00:04.368:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
[10:00:04] Finished 'jshint' after 277 ms
31 07 2015 10:00:04.631:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket sFxRfQ6bJtqM_utNAAAA with id 27252937
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) Services Album service can get an instance of the Album factory FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.addMatchers')
            at /home/matthew/Projects/myapp/tests/services.tests.js:7
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 7 of 7 (1 FAILED) (0.04 secs / 0.022 secs)
[10:00:04] Finished 'karma' after 558 ms
[10:00:04] Starting 'test'...
[10:00:04] Finished 'test' after 11 μs
```

I can't see where I've gone awry. Any ideas? It actually works fine if I take out the custom matcher, which I don't actually use yet, but plan to do so. So it seems like the matcher is the culprit, but since it's literally copied and pasted from the Angular documentation, I'm at a loss as to why it isn't working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved the problem in the end. Turns out that the Jasmine API has changed between 1.3 and 2.0 and the AngularJS documentation doesn't seem to give any information about this. Here's how I fixed the issue so that hopefully anyone else who's stuck on this can find a working solution:

```
describe('Services', function () { 

    beforeEach(function(){
        jasmine.addMatchers({
            toEqualData: function(util, customEqualityTesters) { 
                return { 
                    compare: function(actual, expected) { 
                        return { 
                            pass: angular.equals(actual, expected)
                        };
                    } 
                };
            } 
        });
    });

    beforeEach(module('myapp.services'));

    describe('Album service', function(){
        var Album;

        beforeEach(inject(function (_Album_, _$httpBackend_) { 
            Album = _Album_;
            mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        }));

        it('can get an instance of the Album factory', inject(function (Album) { 
            mockBackend.expectGET('https://myapp.com/api/albums').respond([{id: 1}, {id: 2}]);
            expect(Album).toBeDefined();
            var albums = Album.query();
            mockBackend.flush();
            expect(albums).toEqualData([{id: 1}, {id: 2}]);
        }));
    });
});
```

Basically, all you do is change `this` for `jasmine` when you add the matcher, pass through `actual` and `expected` as arguments to the function, and use them rather than `this`. Seems to work as expected now.

EDIT: Turns out that didn't work, it just failed silently. I've now corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to inject `Album` in your test, but it's an instance. You've already injected `_Album_` in the `beforeEach`.

Try removing the second `inject` (the one in `it()`).

The example in [angulardocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject):

```
// Defined out reference variable outside
var myService;

// Wrap the parameter in underscores
beforeEach( inject( function(_myService_){
  myService = _myService_;
}));

// Use myService in a series of tests.
it('makes use of myService', function() {
  myService.doStuff();
});
```

Comment: No, doesn't make any difference. If I take out the custom matcher it all works, which suggests to me that it's likely that's where the issue lies.

Comment: You're right, sorry.
The error seems to suggest that `angular.equals` is undefined. Can you confirm that it's the case?

Comment: Hmm... `this.addMatchers` shows as undefined when I display it with `console.log()`, which I think may be the source of the problem

Comment: Found it - it's actually a difference between Jasmine 1.3 and Jasmine 2 in terms of how they implement adding a matcher. Rather annoying that the AngularJS documentation doesn't make that clear...